# Phaser 3 sprite keyboard.isDown acting strange

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a snake game in Phaser 3. The arrow.(key).isDown is acting strangely and I can't figure out why. If you press a key weather it is up, down, left or right it will not change directions if you press the opposite, it just keeps moving. like if I press down it keeps going down even after I press up. I have been trying to debug it for hours. All the examples pretty much have it set up the same way.

This is my code so far

```
class mainScene {
  preload() {
    this.load.image("fruit", "images/fruit.png");
    this.load.image("snake", "images/snake.png");
  }
  create() {
    this.score = 0;
    this.snake = this.physics.add.sprite(20, 20, "snake");
    this.fruit = this.physics.add.sprite(
      Phaser.Math.Between(10, 590),
      Phaser.Math.Between(10, 590),
      "fruit"
    );
    this.scoreText = this.add.text(500, 5, `Score: ${this.score}`);
    this.arrow = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    //debug
  }

  update() {
    if (this.physics.overlap(this.snake, this.fruit)) {
      this.hit();
    }
    this.snake.setVelocity(0);
    if (this.arrow.right.isDown) {
      this.snake.setVelocityX(50);
      if (this.snake.x > 600) {
        this.outOfBounds();
      }
    } else if (this.arrow.left.isDown) {
      this.snake.setVelocityX(-50);
      if (this.snake.x < 0) {
        this.outOfBounds();
      }
    }

    if (this.arrow.down.isDown) {
      this.snake.setVelocityY(50);
      if (this.snake.y > 600) {
        this.outOfBounds();
      }
    } else if (this.arrow.up.isDown) {
      this.snake.setVelocityY(-50);
      if (this.snake.y < 0) {
        this.outOfBounds();
      }
    }
  }

  hit() {
    this.fruit.x = Phaser.Math.Between(10, 590);
    this.fruit.y = Phaser.Math.Between(10, 590);
    this.score += 1;
    this.scoreText.setText(`Score: ${this.score}`);

    this.tweens.add({
      targets: this.snake,
      duration: 200,
      scaleX: 1.2,
      scaleY: 1.2,
      yoyo: true,
    });
  }

  outOfBounds() {
    this.score = 0;
    this.scoreText.setText(`Score: ${this.score}`);
    this.gameOverText = this.add.text(
      100,
      250,
      "You went out of bounds.\nGame Over\nPress Space to continue.",
      { fontSize: "24px" }
    );
    if (this.arrow.space.isDown) {
      this.gameOverText.destroy();
      this.scene.restart();
    }
  }
}

const config = {
  type: Phaser.CANVAS,
  width: 600,
  height: 600,
  backgroundColor: 0x000040,
  scene: mainScene,
  physics: {
    default: "arcade",
    debug: true,
    setBounds: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600 },
  },
  parent: "game",
};

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Comment: after looking at it on a few different browsers, it looks like this is a issue on the Brave Browser, which is strange because its a chromium browser, and it works on chrome.